# Generate all possible graphs of size n in Prolog

Tags: prolog, combinations, graph-theory

I'm trying to write a generator to generate all possible graphs of size n in Prolog. Most graphs I've seen in Prolog are represented as a list of facts. I'm thinking about representing it as Graph(Vertices, Edges), e.g.:

```
Graph([Vertex1, Vertex2, Vertex3, ...], [(Vertex1-Vertex2, Vertex2-Vertex3,...)].
```

And the `Generator(G,n)` will find all possible graphs of size n.

I'm having some issues writing the generator because the structure is not recursive. Is it possible to write one in Prolog? How should I approach this? (I'm very new to Prolog) Thanks!

Comment: cold you write it in English first (or any other language)? :) English usually translates into Prolog pretty straightforwardly. Start by taking an inventory of what you have, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: This would not be feasible for any `n` except very small ones.

Comment: Are you also seeking every possible connection for each graph of N Vertices. e.g. no connections to fully connected?

Comment: I recently had to do something similar for binary trees and by referencing [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) it was much easier to find what to expect and how to do it. Is there a math reference such as [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) that would describe these graphs.

Comment: An easy way to start is do one layer of recursion, then add another layer of recursion until you get what you need. Then you can go back and simplify and fold down the predicates if you so desire.